# No text is written to the RichTextBox during a process

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, dispatcher

I have a RichTextBox where I just want to write some info

```
FlowDocument _content = new FlowDocument();

this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
     _content.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("START READING FROM FILE...")));
});

//Code that reads data from an Excel file...

this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
     _content.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("END READING FROM FILE...")));
});
```

But the Start text is never written in The RichTextBox. It is reading from the Excel file but not writing those text into the RichTextBox.

I tried several things that I found here on the site but I can't get text into that RichTextBox during a process..

Comment: Did you set the `Document` property of the`RichTextBox` to `_content`? Then your example works.

Comment: @mm8 Yes indeed I forgot to set the Document to _content, it is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Document` property of the `RichTextBox` to `_content`. Then your example works.